# How to import Android Studio (1.0) project into Intellij 14 Ultimate

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, android-gradle-plugin, intellij-14

I have an Android Studio project and I would like to start using Intellij 14 Ultimate to take advantage of some of the cool features it has to offer. When I try to open my project I get a message saying:

> Gradle Sync
>
> Version 1.0.0-rc4 of the Android Gradle plug-in requires Gradle null or newer. A local Gradle distribution was not found ....
>
> Click 'OK' to use the Gradle wrapper.

I click ok and it tries to Sync, but fails. Here is what the error console says:

> Gradle version 2.2 is required. Current version is 2.1. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in ~gradle-wrapper.properties~

I modify the file click "Try Again"

Nothing happens. Here is what is in the log file:

```
2014-12-13 09:40:23,845 [ 572317]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - null 
java.lang.AssertionError
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.PreSyncChecks.attemptToUpdateGradleVersionInWrapper(PreSyncChecks.java:175)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.PreSyncChecks.ensureCorrectGradleSettings(PreSyncChecks.java:72)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.PreSyncChecks.canSync(PreSyncChecks.java:53)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.GradleProjectImporter.doImport(GradleProjectImporter.java:439)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.GradleProjectImporter.doRequestSync(GradleProjectImporter.java:219)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.GradleProjectImporter.access$000(GradleProjectImporter.java:77)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.GradleProjectImporter$2.run(GradleProjectImporter.java:184)
    at com.intellij.ui.AppUIUtil.invokeLaterIfProjectAlive(AppUIUtil.java:77)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.GradleProjectImporter.requestProjectSync(GradleProjectImporter.java:191)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.GradleProjectImporter.requestProjectSync(GradleProjectImporter.java:166)
    at com.android.tools.idea.editors.ProjectSyncStatusNotificationProvider$ProjectImportFailedNotificationPanel$1.run(ProjectSyncStatusNotificationProvider.java:105)
    at com.intellij.ui.EditorNotificationPanel$2.hyperlinkActivated(EditorNotificationPanel.java:95)
    at com.intellij.ui.HyperlinkAdapter.hyperlinkUpdate(HyperlinkAdapter.java:28)
    at com.intellij.ui.HyperlinkLabel.fireHyperlinkEvent(HyperlinkLabel.java:187)
    at com.intellij.ui.HyperlinkLabel.processMouseEvent(HyperlinkLabel.java:120)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6281)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4872)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4489)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.e(IdeEventQueue.java:748)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:573)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:384)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
2014-12-13 09:40:23,846 [ 572318]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - IntelliJ IDEA 14.0.2  Build #IU-139.659.2 
2014-12-13 09:40:23,846 [ 572318]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - JDK: 1.7.0_71 
2014-12-13 09:40:23,846 [ 572318]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 
2014-12-13 09:40:23,846 [ 572318]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Vendor: Oracle Corporation 
2014-12-13 09:40:23,846 [ 572318]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - OS: Mac OS X 
2014-12-13 09:40:23,846 [ 572318]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Last Action: $Copy
```

I've also tried importing the project and get similar results. Any ideas?

Comment: have you updated all the files in the sdk manager?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Idea support pointed me to this:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-134118

Basically changing my gradle dependency fixed it

```
//For Android Studio
//classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0-rc4'

// For Intellij
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.14.4'
```

Resync and success!

Comment: At the time I write this, IJ 14 is not quite up-to-date with the very latest Android Studio 1.0 release, but Jet Brains knows about it and I think will be synced up with their next release.

Comment: Thanks for the info Scott. Do you know if they plan on keeping AS and the android plugin for intellij in sync? Or will the plugin be slightly behind the latest version of AS?

Comment: Yes to both questions, actually. They pick up the Android Studio/plugin source code from head, but don't release as often.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same thing happening to me tonight, however it provided me with a link to download the latest Gradle dependency. I downloaded it and it solved all of my problems, it will probably solve all of your's too!

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. That makes sense, I'm using the gradlew wrapper, not the downloaded version.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a recent solution, I upgraded to 14.0.3 and it solved the problem.